Possible closed form of the integral contains delta function?
I want to evaluate an $N$-dimensional integral defined by
$$
P(s,k)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm d}x_1\dotsi\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm d}x_N\ \delta\left(\Biggl|\frac{\sum_{m\ne n}^N\exp(i(m+n)k)(x_m-i/2)^{-1}(x_n-i/2)^{-1}}{\sum_{m, n}^N\exp(i(m+n)k)(x_m-i/2)^{-1}(x_n-i/2)^{-1}}\Biggr|^2-s\right)\exp\left(-\frac{\sum_m x^2_m}{2}\right),
$$
where $k$ is real. This integral looks very awful. I wonder if it is possible to obtain a closed form solution?

Where does the integral come from?

@LSpice. It acctually comes from a physical problem of my work, in which I want to calculate the probability density function of the function $|\cdots|^2$ that contains in the dirac delta.

a way to proceed is to work with the Fourier transform $\hat{P}(t,k)$ with respect to $s$, which is given by a Gaussian average $$\hat{P}(t,k)=\int dx_1\cdots \int dx_N  e^{-\sum_m x_m^2/2}\exp\left(i t|1-f_k/g_k^2|^2\right),$$ with the definitions $f_k=\sum_{m}e^{2imk}(x_m-i/2)^{-2},$
$g_k=\sum_{m}e^{imk}(x_m-i/2)^{-1}.$   Numerically, this should be rapidly converging, I may try to see if analytic progress is doable.
